# Problemas com permissão de arquivo SQLite do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

Estou tendo problema com a inicialização do banco de dados SQLite, quando executo o comando `migrate` aparece o erro assim

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file
```

Meu arquivo `.sqlite` está localizado na pasta storage e seu nome é `database.sqlite`.

No meu arquivo de configuração está assim:

```
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => storage_path().'/database.sqlite',
        'prefix' => '',
    ]
```

Não sei o que esta havendo, aparentimente esta tudo normal.

> MEU SISTEMA OPERACIONAL É WINDOWS

Comment: Seu ambiente é windows ou linux? Se for linux tente verificar as permissões do arquivo sqlite.

Comment: meu ambiente é windows

Comment: @RenanRodrigues tenta colocar duas \\ ao invés de /, apenas como teste.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters ainda sim não funcionou

Comment: @RenanRodrigues faça um teste. Digite `php artisan tinker` na pasta do laravel, pela linha de comando. Quando abrir o Tinker, digite `file_exists(storage_path().'/database.sqlite')` para testar se o arquivo realmente existe. Se existir, teste com `is_writable` ou `is_readable`.

Comment: ambos os testes deu como true

Comment: @RenanRodrigues agora faça um outro teste. Coloque todos esses códigos acima dentro de um arquivo `public/temp.php`. E acesse `temp.php` na sua url. A forma que o apache lê as  permissões pode ser diferente (é claro, se o Windows tiver a mesma questões de permissão do que no Linux). Se for o caso (e se puder), delete o arquivo e crie outro, para ver se resolve a situação.

Comment: Qual tem que ser o retorno ? Porque ele mostrou na tela para mim os 3 comandos

Comment: Eu criei o arquivo com touch, será que é por isto ?

Comment: decobri, estava faltando um drive sqlite na minha ide, não sei o porque kkkk

Comment: minto acho que não kkk

Comment: É realmente não funcionou

Comment: O arquivo está na pasta `app/storage/` ou em uma sub-pasta?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento esta na pasta app/storage

Comment: @RenanRodrigues isto `storage_path('database.sqlite')` não funcionou né? Se colocar isto em um controller `return storage_path('database.sqlite');` e apontar pra uma rota, o que o Laravel imprime?

Comment: so minuto para teste

Comment: O caminho de meu arquivo ao certo, na verdade acho que o problema esta com permissão, porém ja tentei dar permissão pelo windows e nao funciona, e utilizei comandos e tambem nada ocorre

Answer (score 1):

A solução foi muito simples e a conseguir sozinho. A página onde meu servidor estava tinha um acento no é, por isto quando tinha que acessar o sistema não funcionava, pois o acento é era substituído por outro caractere.

Como um programador de muito tempo cai nesta besteira, fica a dica para todos tomar cuidado com o nome que damos aos projetos.